# pyspark read file from AWS S3 not working

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, pyspark

I installed spark and hadoop using brew:

```
brew info hadoop #=> hadoop: stable 3.1.2
brew info apache-spark #=> apache-spark: stable 2.4.4
```

I am now trying to load a csv file hosted on s3, tried many different ways without success (here is one of them):

```
import pyspark

conf = pyspark.SparkConf()

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[4]', conf=conf)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", "key here")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", "key here")

sql = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
df = sql.read.csv('s3a://pilo/fi/data_2014_1.csv')
```

I get this error:

```
19/09/17 14:34:52 WARN FileStreamSink: Error while looking for metadata directory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/ingestion/clients/aws_s3.py", line 51, in <module>
    df = sql.read.csv('s3a://pilo/fi/data_2014_1.csv')
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 476, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/cyrusghazanfar/Desktop/startup-studio/pilota_project/pilota_ml/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.csv.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2654)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:547)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary$1.apply(DataSource.scala:545)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:545)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:359)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:618)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        ... 30 more
```

it looks like it has something to do with my aws s3 credentials but not sure how to set that up. (Currently my awe credentiials are in my bash_profile) HELP PLEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the solution [here](https://github.com/CoorpAcademy/docker-pyspark/issues/13) by thisisprabin could be of help?

Add the following to this file "hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>***</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>***</value>
</property>
```

and

```
sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/

sudo cp hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-aws-2.7.5.jar hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Where can I find the location where Hadoop is on my local

Comment: My guess is it is under /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2, and the configuration files are under /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.1.2/libexec/etc/hadoop/.

Comment: Hello @Theofanis , I have installed pyspark through homebrew ,but I can cannot find hadoop folder , able to run pyspark and it is working as expected. do how do I find core-site.xml?